# PHP doesn't send a message with no reason

Tags: php, ts3phpframework

I'm setting up a TS3 Bot using PHP. When I wanted to test whether something works (sending a message to the site), nothing happens.
Code:

```
<?php
    define("host", "localhost");
    define("QueryName", "serveradmin");
    define("Nickname", "Test BOT");
    define("Password", "");
    define("QueryPort", "10011");
    define("ServerPort", "9987");

    echo "Test";
    echo host;
    echo QueryName;
    echo Nickname;
    echo Password;
    echo QueryPort;
    echo ServerPort;
?>
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the `$ts` variable. What are you expecting exactly?

Comment: Are you sure about the "with no reason"? Because von Neumann computers actually work in a deterministic manner. They don't do something for "no reason"... It is _always_ you as a programmer who causes the behavior.

Comment: Maybe i'm not doing anything but when I add before ```error_reporting[..]``` echo "works"; it doesn't show up. It should show Exception on website because password is incorrect